# Typing mongoose discriminators

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to make my TypeScript interfaces work with my discriminated mongoose models but I'm unable to get the base model type to understand what different discriminator tag it has. Is it even possible to have TS infer this or will I have to explicitly type this myself?